# How to display the progress wizard vertically using css in angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass

here i am working on the progress wizard i created a horizontal progress wizard so here how i can make it to vertical or is there any library ?

below is my stackblitz url
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-n6dp3x

css:

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch; /* Default */
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

li {
    display: block;
    flex: 0 1 auto; /* Default */
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0 0.75em;
    z-index: 1;
}

li:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
}

li:last-child {
    padding-right: 0;
}

ul:after {
    content: '';
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flex-direction: column;` to display the `li` vertically and set height with border-left.

```css
ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch; /* Default */
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

li {
    display: block;
    flex: 0 1 auto; /* Default */
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0 0.75em;
    z-index: 1;
}


ul {
  flex-direction: column;
}

li {
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 55px;
}

ul li:before {
    /* lines */
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px; /* adjust manually */
    border-left: 1px solid lightgray;
    height: 60px;
    width: 1px;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it didnt work out for me can u change in my stackblitz url ?

Comment: did that please chek this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-n6dp3x

Comment: its working now and a small doubt suppose if i want to display any content beside <li>1</li> then ? say a paragraph kind of